# Example where $\{g \in G \mid \phi(g) = g^{-1}\}$ is not a subgroup for $\phi \in {\rm Aut}(G)$

Tags: group-theory

> Let be $G$ a group and $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Give an example in which the subset
>
> $$I(G,\phi)=\{g\in G \mid \phi(g)=g^{-1} \}$$
>
> is not a subgroup of $G$.

Is easy to see that, if $G$ is abelian, then $I(G,\phi)$ is a subgroup.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the automorphisms there surely is the identity map. What does it mean that $g=g^{-1}$? And is the set of such elements a subgroup? (Hint: consider a small nonabelian group).

Comment: Ok!Let $G=S_{3}$ and $(12)(23)=(123)$ ans $(123)$ not is involution. Now if $/phi$ has order 2, it will be worth the same?

Comment: @User2040 Yes: the set of elements such that $g=g^{-1}$ (or $g^2=1$) in the group $S_3$ consists of four elements, and so it's no a subgroup. Or the product of distinct involutions is not an involution, it's OK. Think to the simple cases before going to the complex ones. `;-)`

Comment: Ok! Very goof!Now if $\phi$ has order 2, it will be worth the same?